# match files .c on tasks.json to compile

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, gcc

i'm using the microsoft extension on vscode to compile C, the problem is, with one file .c, ok, but when i include some lib, like conio.c, i need to tell manually to compile this file too putting the name of the file in the tasks.json, i want to do this automatically, but i can't add any "pattern" in tasks.json, and i don't know if .json runs regex, thanks in advance! Basically i want to match all .c that i'm using in the main program.

```
    {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}"  ---add name of file to here compile---,
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Tarefa gerada pelo Depurador."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: if you use more than 1 .c file use a build tool, Make, CMake, MSBuild, ...., the reason to prevent to recompile all stuff for each build

Comment: sorry man, i didn't understand, maybe for lack of acknowledgement about the topic, can you explain detailed? thanks for the answer

Comment: do a web search for the different tools and there you will get 1000+ hits to learn, there is a CMake extension for VSC

Comment: i remember that i fixed that one time, but don't remember, and using just the tasks.json

Comment: if someone could help me with this i would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}\\**.c",
        "${fileDirname}\\**.h",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\bin\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Tarefa gerada pelo Depurador."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of adding `.h` files to the compile command

Comment: i think i'm just sleepy kkkkkk, but this answer my question, thank god, can go to bed now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you incorporate `"\\"` within your file path to accommodate spaces (so escaping the double quotes in the `args` variable) to prevent potential errors. Below is the modified code snippet:

```
"args": [
    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
    "-g3",
    "\"${fileDirname}\"/**.c",
    "-lm",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
],
```